# Inserting Data Using PHP Curl

Tags: php, api, curl

I am trying to add the following data to my database using curl. It insert's the data but the data inserted is blank

Employee Name = Test

Employee Salary = 100

Employee Age = 28

This is my code in inserting the data:

```
// set post fields
$data["employee_name"] = "test";
$data["employee_salary"] = 1;
$data["employee_age"] = 1;

$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/cloud/v1/employees');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

// execute!
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// close the connection, release resources used
curl_close($ch);

// do anything you want with your response
var_dump($response);
```

This is my Function in getting the data :

```
function insert_employee()
    {
        global $connection;

        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
        $employee_name=$data["employee_name"];
        $employee_salary=$data["employee_salary"];
        $employee_age=$data["employee_age"];
        echo $query="INSERT INTO employee SET employee_name='".$employee_name."', employee_salary='".$employee_salary."', employee_age='".$employee_age."'";
        if(mysqli_query($connection, $query))
        {
            $response=array(
                'status' => 1,
                'status_message' =>'Employee Added Successfully.'
            );
        }
        else
        {
            $response=array(
                'status' => 0,
                'status_message' =>'Employee Addition Failed.'
            );
        }
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: If you are json_decoding, you have to json_encode your data before sending it.

Comment: can you paste echo $query="INSERT INTO employee SET employee_name='".$employee_name."', employee_salary='".$employee_salary."', employee_age='".$employee_age."'"; here ?

Comment: use `$_POST` instead of `file_get_contents('php://input')`  Try as `$employee_name=$_POST["employee_name"];`

Comment: your data is sent using `multipart/form-data` encoding, and then you're trying to parse the multipart-data with a JSON-parser. the JSON parser doesn't understand `multipart/form-data`. but PHP has a built-in multipart parser which already put all your data in $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

`$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);`

with:

`$data = $_POST;`

PHP will take your POSTed data and push it straight into a global `$_POST` array. No need to play with `json_decode` (unless you have posted a JSON string) or `php://input`.

Be aware, however, that blindly trusting posted data, and concatenating posted variables into a SQL statement is a huge security hole! Please look in to prepared statements and input validation.